# jhipster add relationship between 2 existing tables

Tags: relationship, jhipster, liquibase

I added a relationship between 2 existing tables, and regenerate with function "jhipster import-jdl" but when I launch application, I have an error with liquibase :

```
2017-10-02 11:45:02.968 ERROR 9036 --- [idia-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready: Validation Failed:
 2 change sets check sum
      config/liquibase/changelog/20171002091222_added_entity_Utilisateur.xml::20171002091222-1::jhipster was: 7:716203e07c10f181f65dd9531b803796 but is now: 7:5bad37468d044f75f42287e794d6dd97
      config/liquibase/changelog/20171002091222_added_entity_constraints_Utilisateur.xml::20171002091222-2::jhipster was: 7:b56406e6f7f1206accc2de82f799bd40 but is now: 7:1123b5400c7cbbb680fc9a10c7278ca0


liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
 2 change sets check sum
      config/liquibase/changelog/20171002091222_added_entity_Utilisateur.xml::20171002091222-1::jhipster was: 7:716203e07c10f181f65dd9531b803796 but is now: 7:5bad37468d044f75f42287e794d6dd97
      config/liquibase/changelog/20171002091222_added_entity_constraints_Utilisateur.xml::20171002091222-2::jhipster was: 7:b56406e6f7f1206accc2de82f799bd40 but is now: 7:1123b5400c7cbbb680fc9a10c7278ca0

    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.validate(DatabaseChangeLog.java:266)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:210)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:431)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:388)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:82)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:64)
    at io.github.jhipster.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.lambda$createWrappedRunnable$1(ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What do I have to do for add relationship on existing tables?

I must to add xml changelog for liquibase manually? and update checksum??

Thank  you!

Vince

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not in production and don't have data to keep, just drop your database and let your app re-create it.

Otherwise, create a new migration manually or using liquibase diff to add relationship. Migrations are supposed to be immutable, that's why Liquibase checksums them and when you want to add something to the past structure you should add new migration rather than modifying an old one.

Comment: Ok, I can drop database, bu in production? How I can do that?

Comment: What don't you understand in my second alternative?

Comment: I thought jhipster would automatically handle it

Comment: This is a complex task, someone is working on a PR to improve things though it's not ready and might not cover your particular use case. See https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/6016